# How to handle unknown-length header (TFTP related)

Tags: header, tftp

It is probably relevant to other questions too.
I need to build a simple TFTP server in C (octet mode only) that will work with most TFTP clients available today (I only need to implement the server).

```
opcode   //2 byte
filename // string (unknown size)
0        // 1 byte
mode     // string (unknows size, max 9 chars considering 'netascii')
0        // 1 byte
```

But I'm having a problem: the RRQ/WRQ packets have a unknown length field "filename" (and "mode"). Because my server needs to be generic, how can I implement this option?
Create a ridiculously large buffer and wait until recvfrom() returns 0?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make the buffer no much larger than the payload size of an Ethernet packet...
with TFTP recvfrom won't return buffers larger than that...